# How do I get the size of a download when a HEAD request doesn't report ContentLength?

Tags: delphi, size

Using this code in Delphi for getting a web page size: (I mean page source size)

```
uses
  IdHTTP

function URLsize(const URL : string) : integer;
var
  Http: TIdHTTP;
begin
  Http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    Http.Head(URL);    
    result := round(Http.Response.ContentLength / 1048576);   //MB   
  finally
    Http.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I can get file size easily for some URLs like `http://sample.com/test.exe`. It returns the size in MB.

But I cannot get URL size using this code for a URL like `http://stackoverflow.com/`; it returns `0` or `-1`.

How can I get the size in that case?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165926/using-wininet-to-identify-total-file-size-before-downloading-it

Comment: @JerryDodge I tried that. But didn't help. Still can't get the size. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Of course. The accepted answer to that Q does exactly the same as here. HEAD request followed by read of content-length.

Comment: That's why I said related and not duplicate.

Comment: I'm getting a content-length with `http://stackoverflow.com/`.

Comment: When I test `http://stackoverflow.com/` using your exact function, I get 0 - but without dividing it I get 194569, which is smaller than 1048576. Could this be your problem?

Comment: Content-length is typically only universally supported when it comes to downloading files (program installers, general data files like DOC and PDF).  It usually (thought always but just checked and SO does return content-lengths on text) is not supported when it comes to text data, so the functions involved will usually return -1.  A good rule is to not expect content-length from the web server and write your code so it is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: For the record, yesterday I downloaded some software, and although the file size was about 10 MB, Google Chrome didn't show an expected time, or percent complete, because it didn't know how big the file was. The server didn't include this in the header. Still, Chrome respectfully downloaded it regardless of this field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not all HTTP HEAD responses contain content-length. So, what you are trying to do is impossible in general. If you encounter a response that does not contain the content length you need to download the contents in order to find the length.

Comment: But some softwares like **Internet Download Manager** or **Internet Download Accelerator** can get the size of a webpage. Without downloading the whole page. How do they do this?

Comment: What is your evidence that they do actually do that? How would they manage to do that for a file that was generated dynamically?

Comment: I added a URL to Internet Download Accelerator **without downloading it** (of course I clicked on _Download Later_). Then right-clicked on the URL and clicked on _Get File Size_ and it showed me the size without downloading it

Comment: @Sky: David is correct. Not all `HEAD` requests (or `GET` requests, for that matter) can provide a `Content-Length` header (the `TIdHTTP.Response.HasContentLength` property will tell you if the header was present). That is the official way to get the file size without downloading the actual file. If a download manager is able to get the size and you are not, then the manager is relying on other info. You would have to look at the actual `HEAD` response to see what other data is being reported. `http://stackoverflow.com/` does have a `Content-Length` header, though.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan & @RemyLebeau Yeah. Got my answer. Thanks to David. I checked & `http://stackoverflow.com/` does have a `Content-Length`.  But now I wonder how can I get `Content Length` from `stackoverflow.com`. It's a dynamic page right? And David said that it's impossible to get length from a dynamic web site. Because it generates the html code while the whole page is loading/downloadng.

Comment: If stackoverflow.com does supply content length for HEAD, then surely Indy will pass it on.

Comment: If a `Content-Length` header is present, Indy will indeed provide it. StackOverflow (and other servers) can provide a `Content-Length` header if they know up front what the total file size actually is, even for dynamically created content. It is when content is being sent while it is being created, such as with a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header, where `Content-Length` is either not present because the size is unknown until the end of the request, or it is present but 0 (even though it is not supposed to be present, but some servers do that).

Comment: So again, if a DM is getting the file size and you are not, then the DM has to be looking at something else, so you need to look at the full response to see what else you can look at.

Comment: @Sky, check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-length.php#13715) out.

Answer (score 3):

Even if a web server does return the proper content length, you're dividing it by `1048576` to get the megabyte value. Since `http://stackoverflow.com/` is much less than a single megabyte, it is returning `0`. I'm still stumped however where your `-1` came from - because `http://stackoverflow.com/` returns `194569` for me, without dividing. Did you get a `-1` from another website? And are your results the divided value or the raw value from `Http.Response.ContentLength`?

Comment: @jerryDodge yes. because the size is less than megabyte it returns 0. But my problem was something (I get `-1` for `http://www.google.com/`.) + With the code above, when I get `content-length` of StackOveflow it returns `196444` (without dividing it). But when I load the site with a browser and save the page source to a text file, the text size is `228154`. I don't know why. It's kinda confusing.

Comment: @Sky That's because elements get added to the page dynamically through script. Nothing confusing about that. Download the raw file *before* the script starts adding it returns 194569, but *after* the script has added new contents, it becomes roughly 228154 which varies depending on the data which was loaded dynamically.

Comment: Also, StackOverflow constantly makes changes, so the size may have changed since your test and my test, etc.