# C (WinAPI) - get size of internet file

Tags: c, file, winapi

I download files from the Internet using InternetOpenUrl and InternetReadFile. How do I get the size of a file prior to downloading? When downloading manually from the Internet, you can see total size just as the download process begins, but how do I get that size?

Comment: What platform?  What API did you use?

Comment: WinAPI, Windows added to OP

Comment: I think this question has been answered previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165926/using-wininet-to-identify-total-file-size-before-downloading-it

Answer (score 4):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384238%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you should use `HttpQueryInfo` to get the size of a resource accessed with `InternetOpenUrl`. The corresponding query flag is called `HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH`.

Comment: Can I use HINTERNET returned by InternetOpenUrl? If so, why does it fail?
DWORD size = 0;
DWORD r1=256, r2=0;
HttpQueryInfoA(hFile, HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH| HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER, &size, &r1, &r2);

Comment: @Dan: A wild guess: You are passing a `DWORD` as your receive buffer, and yet you are telling the API, that it is 256 bytes in size.

Comment: That was left from previous try when I tried using char array as a buffer. Tried setting it now to 4 bytes, but still it fails for some reason. Although the download works fine.

Comment: @Dan: [HttpQueryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384238.aspx): *"Returns **TRUE** if successful, or **FALSE** otherwise. To get extended error information, call **[GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx)**."*

Comment: Here is the error I get : ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND
The requested header could not be located.

Comment: Try to open a handle for your URL with [HttpOpenRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using "GET" as verb. Although I don't see why it wouldn't work with your handle as it is.